# My Menu Disappears on my Custom Link Homepage on Mobile

Tags: menus

My menu on my custom link homepage disappears on mobile, or when the window is small on web browsing.

The thing is on all my other pages on mobile, the menu is there in the form of three lines - as a drop down menu. It is on every other page, except for my static custom link homepage.

Any ideas?

I saw the similar question and answer on this website, in relation to going into menu and setting it as primary menu - mine is set as primary menu and did not resolve the issue.

website: www.racheldhanjal.com

Rachel

Comment: This is because your theme hide `<div class='navigation-wrapper'></div>`. Please check your self for that.

Comment: FYI, there is some JS error into your site like `TypeError: this.ajaxForm is not a function`. Please correct it first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mobile nav menu in your theme appears to be injected via JavaScript.  On pages other than the home page the mobile nav does appear.  It looks like the home page is the only page throwing JS errors; they appear to be associated with Mailchimp and/or Contact form 7 .  Try disabling plugins for both Mailchimp and CF7.

Answer (score 0):

You added the menu only for the destop view. For mobile menu goto dashboard->Appearence->menu->Menusetting-> select theme location for mobile